# C# datetimepicker to date in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I get an exception whenever I try changing value of `DateTimePicker` in C# application if I don't change it the program runs successfully - any ideas?

Exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string.

C# code :

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TDI11-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mjhd;Integrated Security=True");
    String req = "insert into dommage_materiel values('" + textBox1.Text +"','" + richTextBox2.Text+ "','" + richTextBox1.Text +"','" + textBox3.Text + "','" +dateTimePicker1.Value+"','" + richTextBox3.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','" + textBox5.Text.ToString()+"')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(req, cnx);

    cnx.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnx.Close();
}
```

I tried this methods nothing worked:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());

Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```

Note : SQL Server column datatype is `Date`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try passing parameters? That way you can specify the parameter type as well. Just to give an example :

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@dateParamter", SqlDbType.Date);
command.Parameters["@dateParamter"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

You can read more about this here : [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, `dynamic SQL` as above is prone to `SQL injection`. `Parameterised SQL` is at the very least a good beginning point in learning to prevent them.

For more information, you can read [Jeff Atwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood)'s article [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Just to borrow the bottomline from the aforementioned article :

> `Parameterised SQL` offers the following pure performance benefits:
>
> - Fewer string concatenations
> - No need to worry about any kind of manual string escaping
> - A more generic query form is presented to db, so it's likely already hashed and stored as a pre-compiled execution plan
> - Smaller strings are sent across the wire
>
> Non-parameterized SQL is the GoTo statement of database programming.
>   Don't do it, and make sure your coworkers don't either.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks, it help's a lot but the problem still  acures .